# 413Request Entity Too Large using Spring cloud routing

Tags: heroku, spring-cloud

Need help with given issue. I am using Spring cloud routing to create simple Api-gateway service with Heroku. 
I am accepting the request and redirecting it to another heroku service.
I am trying to redirect simple GET method, without any params or body. 
Unfortunately, i am accepting 413 Request Entity Too Large error.

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {     
    return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r
                    .path("/auth/**")
                    .filters(defaultFilters())
                    .uri(AUTH_URL)
                    .id("authModule"))
            .route(r -> r
                    .path("/task-provider/**")
                    .filters(defaultFilters())
                    .uri(TASK_PROVIDER_URL)
                    .id("taskProviderModule"))
            .build(); 


Here are the routes
var AUTH_URL[enter image description here][1]=https://greenapp-auth-service.herokuapp.com/
var TASK_PROVIDER_URL=https://greenapp-task-provider.herokuapp.com/
```

**These I have in my heroku application logs:**

```
2020-05-29T20:37:31.777338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/sign/test" 
host=greenapp-gateway.herokuapp.com request_id=4198d326-91c0-4578-9eae-8a779195ad54 
fwd="5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47,34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 3. 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47, 
34.255.41.27,5.164.220.47,34.255.41.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=854ms status=413 
bytes=533 protocol=https
```

Comment: why is that header so large?

Comment: now idea, it is generated by heroku

Comment: The entity too large is generated by reactor netty, not sure there's anything I can do